How to convert this date Wednesday July 31 2024 11:20 am to a short date (MM/DD/YY)?
I have my time/date column like this:

Wednesday, July 31, 2024, 11:20 am

But I need it too look like MM/DD/YY in Excel. What formula can I use?

First, check if excel doesn't actually already recognizes the date as a real date, because if that is the case, you can just right-click the cell, cell properties, and change the notation there.

Please update your question with the answer to LPChips remark: what format are the cells in?

If you are US Locale, or using US Settings for Date & Time then simply use TEXTBEFORE() & TEXTAFTER()


=--TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,", "),", ",-1)


This will return the output as a number, please format it as mm/dd/yyyy

Or, if you want to use more Step-By-Step method then:
=LET(
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A1,{" ",", "}),
     b, MONTH(CHOOSECOLS(a,2)&0),
     c, CHOOSECOLS(a,3),
     d, CHOOSECOLS(a,4),
     DATE(d,b,c))



Where --> a --> Splits the string column wise using TEXTSPLIT().
Where --> b --> Grab the 2nd column value using CHOOSECOLS() and convert it to month number using MONTH() function.
Where --> c --> Using CHOOSECOLS() grab the day.
Where --> d --> Using CHOOSECOLS() grab the year.
Finally --> Using DATE() place each variable in the required arguments to get the desired output.


Also, if you are reluctant to use a formula, you can also accomplish the desired output using Text-To-Columns From Data Tab


The whole process is outlines in the demo:

Select the range.
Goto Data Tab.
Click Text To Columns.
First Step --> Select --> Fixed Width --> Next.
Second Step --> Adjust the line breaks, so that only the month,day and year are within one, like i have shown.
Third Step --> Select the columns from Data Preview and hit ALT+I (Do not import column(skip), select the date column and hit ALT+D lastly, click finish.
And then just format as per your preference.



We need to reorganize the order of the "words" to make it into a date that is acceptable to Excel then we can convert it to a date that you can then apply the correct format to the cell.
=--TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," "),,{3,2,4,5,6}))

The Substitute removes all the ,.
The TEXTSPLIT then splits on the space.
Then the INDEX reorders it.
And finally we put it back together in the correct order and the -- converts it to a date.
Then format the cell to MM/DD/YY

One note.  This retains the time portion of the date but the number format of the cell hides it.  If trying to do matching on it that will need to be dealt with.
One way would be to remove the ,5,6 from the array and it will not include the time:
=--TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")," "),,{3,2,4}))


Sir, SUBSTITUTE() not required : =--TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{" ",", "}),{3,2,4}))
